# How to retrieve page's slug from Wikipedia API

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

Let's suppose that I what to make a query to Wikipedia API to fetch all pages. APIs return the title of all pages but I have not found a way to retrieve the slug of them. For example

Title: Keith R. Porter
Slug: Keith_R._Porter

If that is not possible, do you know if there exists a way to find the function that, in MediaWiki, transforms title in slug?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace spaces with underscores and urlencode. If you really don't want to do it yourself, the [info API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Info) (among a number of other things) provides URLs. Internally, Title objects have a number of methods for getting URLs.